# Use of IFDEF for giving an attribute

Tags: dll, fortran

I have the following working situation in a .f90 file that is generating a dynamic library (DLL in Windows, SO in Linux):

```
#ifdef __linux__
    subroutine FCCORR (i1,i2) bind(c, name='FCCORR')
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
#endif
!
#ifdef _WIN32
    subroutine FCCORR (i1,i2)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS : "FCCORR" :: FCCORR
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: i1,i2
#endif
!
integer, intent(in)  :: i1
integer, intent(out) :: i2
!
i2 = i1*3
!
end subroutine
```

I want to know if it's possible to avoid the separation of subroutines in the two different cases: in particular I want to know if it's possible to use the `#ifdef` for appending the `bind` attribute only, like this:

```
subroutine FCCORR (i1,i2)
#ifdef __linux__
    bind(c, name='FCCORR')
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
#endif
!
#ifdef _WIN32
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS : "FCCORR" :: FCCORR
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: i1,i2
#endif
!
integer, intent(in)  :: i1
integer, intent(out) :: i2
!
i2 = i1*3
!
end subroutine
```

But obviously line 3 produce an error:

> (error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one
>   of: ::  /
>       bind(c, name='TEST')

Comment: Have you tried the SUBROUTINE inside the #ifdef(s) ?

Comment: This is not Fortran 90, tag removed.

Comment: @Holmz sure he did, see the first code block in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is possible, but you must use the Fortran rules for line continuation

```
subroutine FCCORR (i1,i2) &
#ifdef __linux__
    bind(c, name='FCCORR')
```

the problem is that you need to continue the line somehow in the Windows case too and there is no option I can see for that.

But I don't understand why you cant use the `bind(C)` attribute in Windows as well.

BTW, I definitely can't see why you use `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding` because there is no reference to the module in the code. If the code needed it, it would have been needed also in the Windows version.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, you're totally right; in fact I don't need `iso_c_binding`, while in Windows I need the `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT`, so I can't use `bind(C)`.

I solved using `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DECORATE, ALIAS "TEST" :: TEST` for Linux and `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS "TEST" :: TEST` for Windows.

Thanks for your help

Comment: As far as I know `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT` can be combined with `bind(C)`.

Comment: You're right again, `bind(C)` can't be combined with `ALIAS` or `DECORATE`... BTW I've solved with a walk-around, like I wrote above... Should I delete the question?

Comment: Once you accepted a question you could be penalized if you unaccept it and delete the question. The system does not like it.

Comment: But the final call is yours, just something to be aware of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287903/721644 *"Finally, it's worth noting a particular case where deleting questions counts heavily toward a question ban: deleting them right after someone posts an answer."* Maybe just wait for some time...

Comment: I would not delete the question, this is the best one I have seen all month.